# When I upload page on my website ...Its not getting loaded altogether...its getting loaded in patches

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

When I upload page on my website. 
Its not getting loaded altogether.
Its getting loaded in patches.

```
//$("#idUpcmgMtch").append(nwhtml); 
//var slyObj = scrlr(); slyObj.reload();
var actid="";
    if(pagename="create-team"){$("li[upcomingmatch="+match_id+"]").addClass("active");
    }
else{
$("#2").addClass("active");
}/////
```

this script is uselesss...I have added it bcoz it was not accepting my question. 
suggest me some solution or links where I can refer..........I want to make my web site load properly.

Comment: A this point there is to few information to answer this. This can be caused by serval causes.. Please specify, also I have no clue what u mean with 'in patches'

Comment: carousals and other data like image is getting displayed slowly .......

Comment: Did u compress the images for the web? If every images is >2MB then no wonder it will be slow

Comment: Is 2mb a limit ....dats wat is causing it to load slowly????

Comment: This question is too common. You need to isolate a case that shows your problem and explain what the expected results would be. Posting bogus only to let the question pass the filters is also bad. And please use proper language.

Comment: Lets say people have an averge internet connection of 1MBs and all your images are lets say 1MB, this would mean that the page load is at least 1 * 1 * amount of images (ex.20) = 20sec

Answer (score 0):

That is because browser loads things in order, there are many things that go into the mix for getting the content on the screen.
And some of the steps (in sequence are )

```
 1.Request-Response
 2.Parse HTML and produce DOM
 3.Recalculate Styles
 4.Render Tree
 5.Laying out the Document
 6.Rasterization 
 7.Layering
```

By the way if you want to make things appear in one go, then make `body` as `display:none`
and on `document.ready`  make it `display` block.

Thanks